# What is a good way to insert an entity with dependencies using TableController?

Tags: entity-framework-6, azure-mobile-services, dto

I am struggling to insert a new entity which references other existing entities using table controller in azure mobile services.

This is my set up:

Entities:

```
public class EntityB : EntityData
{
   public EntityA Parent { get; set; }
   //some data
}

public class EntityA : EntityData
{
   //some data
}
```

Dtos:

```
public class DtoEntityB : EntityData
{
   public DtoEntityA Parent { get; set; }
   //some data
}

public class DtoEntityA : EntityData
{
   //some data
}
```

Controller:

```
public class Controller : TableController<DtoEntityB>
{
   public virtual async Task<DtoEntityB> Post(DtoEntityB entity)
   {
      return await InsertAsync(entity);
   }    
}
```

Mapper:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
   // use other mapper
   cfg.CreateMap<DtoEntityB, EntityB>();
   cfg.CreateMap<EntityB, DtoEntityB>();

   cfg.CreateMap<DtoEntityA, EntityA>();
   cfg.CreateMap<EntityA, DtoEntityA>();
}
```

EntityA exists already, so I make a client call which results in JSON sent to the Post method. Then everything works fine until EF tells me that there is already an EntityA with id = 317238621736.

```
{
   "EntityA" : {
    "Id" : "317238621736"}
}
```

I am looking for a generic solution for this problem (right now I do direct operations on the context (attach) for every existing reference, combing this with Mapper makes this approach unsustainable.